# Use the output of one module in the output of a second module

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I am using Terraform to create mssql servers and databases in Azure.  I can successfully create these resources, but when I want to get connection strings to add to App Configuration I get a bit stymied on collecting the FQDN from the server.

I have two modules at `modules/mssql_server` and `modules/mssql_database`

`modules/mssql_server` looks like this:

```
#### main.tf ####

resource "azurerm_mssql_server" "mssql_server" {
  for_each = var.mssql_servers

  name                = "${local.name.prefix}-${each.value.name}-${local.name.suffix}-${each.value.location}-${each.value.instance_count}"
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group[each.value.resource_group].name
  location            = each.value.location
  tags                = merge(var.global_settings.common_tags, local.common_tags, local.extra_tags)
  version             = each.value.version

  azuread_administrator {
    login_username              = each.value.login_username
    object_id                   = each.value.object_id
    tenant_id                   = var.tenant_id
    azuread_authentication_only = each.value.azure_auth_only
  }
}


#### variables.tf ####

variable "global_settings" {}

variable "environment" {
  type        = string
  description = "from environment vars"
}
variable "resource_group" {}
variable "tenant_id" {}

variable "mssql_servers" {}


#### outputs.tf ####

output "sql_servers" {
  value = { for k, server in azurerm_mssql_server.mssql_server :
    k => ({ "name" = server.name, "id" = server.id, "fqdn" = server.fully_qualified_domain_name })
  }
}
```

My `modules/mssql_database` looks like this:

```
#### main.tf ####

resource "azurerm_mssql_database" "mssql_database" {
  for_each = var.mssql_databases

  name = "${local.name.prefix}-${each.value.name}-${local.name.suffix}-${each.value.location}-${each.value.instance_count}"
  tags = merge(var.global_settings.common_tags, local.common_tags, local.extra_tags)

  server_id = var.mssql_server[each.value.sql_server].id
  collation = "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"
  sku_name = each.value.sku_name
  
  server_fqdn = var.mssql_server[each.value.sql_server].fqdn


}

#### variables.tf ####

variable "global_settings" {}

variable "environment" {
  type        = string
  description = "from environment vars"
}
variable "mssql_server" {}
variable "mssql_databases" {}

#### outputs.tf ####


output "database" {
  value = { for d, database in azurerm_mssql_database.mssql_database :
    d => ({ "name" = database.name,
            "id" = database.id,
            "server_id" = database.server_id,
            "fqdn" = database.server_fqdn, 
    })
  }
}
```

I get the following when running terraform apply:

```
│ Error: Unsupported argument
│
│   on modules/mssql_database/main.tf line 15, in resource "azurerm_mssql_database" "mssql_database":
│   15:   server_fqdn = var.mssql_server[each.value.sql_server].fqdn
│
│ An argument named "server_fqdn" is not expected here.
```

I think I want the FQDN from the server module to be incorporated into the output of the database module so that I can use it in the formulation of a valid connection string, so that I can access that connection string in a third module (not shown here).

Can I pass an output value through a module like this?

Is there a better way to skin this cat?

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Are you invoking both of the modules in one root module or you just want to pass the value between the two? If the latter is what you want, I'm afraid you can't do that.

Comment: I invoke the server module in a root module, and then invoke the database module in the root module.    I am passing the outputs of server into database (which includes fqdn), but seem to be unable to then pass the fqdn through as an output of the database module.  Since I am using for_each to create each server, and using for_each again to create each database, I need the fqdn to be outputted by the database module - unless there is another way....

Comment: You could define an input variable in the `mysql_database` module and reference it in the FQDN. In the module call, it would get the value from the output of the `mssql_server` module.

Comment: @MarkoE, But then I get an error saying that server_fqdn is not expected in the mssql_database module